IMAP Error: EXPUNGE not allowed in session state when creating folder in Laravel
When trying to use the EXPUNGE command after creating folders with the IMAP server, we receive the following error:
BAD [ALERT] i.<unique_id> EXPUNGE not allowed in session state
The EXPUNGE command is issued immediately after creating a folder.
The IMAP server responds with the error, indicating that EXPUNGE is not allowed in the current session state.
Request:
Could you please verify if EXPUNGE is supported in this session context?
If EXPUNGE should be used, are there specific conditions or sequence requirements to apply it correctly?
Thank you for your assistance.

You must have a folder SELECTed to use EXPUNGE.   What are you hoping to accomplish by using EXPUNGE, as that is only for removing \Deleted messages?

To correctly use the EXPUNGE command, follow this sequence:

Connect to the IMAP server.
Authenticate using LOGIN or AUTHENTICATE command.
Select a mailbox using the SELECT or EXAMINE command.
Mark messages for deletion using the STORE or UID STORE command.
Issue the EXPUNGE command to permanently remove the marked messages.

